# flutter: No named parameter with the name 'clipBehavior', clipBehavior: Clip.none

Tags: flutter, badge

I am trying to add a notifications counter badge with using badges package with flutter but the project does not compile as soon as I add the below code. I'm using flutter `v1.17.4`.

```
Badge(
  badgeColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  toAnimate: true,
  child: IconButton(
   icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
   onPressed: (){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ShoppingCart()));
   }
 )
),
```

When start debugging, `flutter: No named parameter with the name 'clipBehavior', clipBehavior: Clip.none` displays. Is there any possible solution without `Updating the version of flutter to latest version`?

Comment: Which version of Badge package are you using? It seems the author has a fix for clipBehavior in the latest version 1.1.6. please see https://pub.dev/packages/badges/changelog.

Comment: I used version 1.1.5. I will try with the latest version. Thank you @bluenile

Comment: Please let me know if it works, I'll post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is working . Thank you again @bluenile

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, please up-vote and accept the answer if you wish. Thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not from the Flutter framework but from the older version of Badge package that you are using. The author of Badge has updated the package on December 8, 2020 with precise the same bug fix.

> [1.1.6] - [December 8, 2020]
>
> Fix error parameter with the name 'clipBehavior'

Please upgrade the Badge package to its latest version Badges 1.1.6.